# how to save the data which was given inside of ckeditor into database

Tags: razor, ckeditor, razorengine

hello I am very new to asp.net mvc I need to save the data given in ck editor

i did like this i downloaded the ck editor from the internet and pasted in my solution explorer 
 given the path in view

path is like this:

```
             <script src="~/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

written razor code for text area:

```
          @Html.TextArea("editor", new {@class = "ckeditor", @id = "aboutme"})
```

how to save this data in database

Comment: hi the data is saving in database in between the html tags  like                           <p>hello sql hello sql<p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic usage of ckeditor is as follows:

```
 @Html.TextArea("editor", htmlAttributes: new { name = "editor", id = "editor", rows = "10", cols = "180" })
```

and configure your ckeditor as :

```
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor',
 {
     height: 450
 });
</script>
```

and while posting data to httpPost controller do this :

```
    [ValidateInput(false)]    <-------
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult YourController(FormCollection formValues)
    {
     //You can get value of ckeditor as
     var temp =  formValues["editor"]; //it will have complete data inside ckeditor you can save it to database as the way you want.
    }
```

**Make sure to add ValidateInput(false) because ckeditor provides output as html with html tags but in asp.net mvc due to security reasons they give exception when we post html tags so ValidateInput(false) will solve the purpose.**

**Make sure to add complete folder named ckeditor in your root folder of your project and also provide reference of js file in your view**

Comment: @user3496982 i think above code is enough for you to work with ckeditor.

Comment: @user3496982 need more help??

Comment: hi the data is saving with html tags how we can avoid this things regards sumanth

Comment: ckeditor always save data with html tags you cannot avoid it,this is the feature of editor then what's the use of using editor if you don't want to save data with html tags....@sumanthb

Comment: im using the ckeditor in job post screen while view the data in partial screen the data is also reading the html so i don't need that tags in view the data THANKS

Comment: you have to decode that data so that html tags are not shown in browser as Server.HtmlDecode(// your editor data //) at controller side.

Comment: when you are getting data from database then in controller where you are getting ckeditor data just decode as Server.HtmlDecode(// your editor data //)

Comment: nope it is not working with Sever.HtmlDecode(jobDetails.DESCR) regards